# Adding page by page security/authentication in MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, security, model-view-controller, active-directory

I am looking to add page by page security/authentication for a website. All users are logged in via Active Directory. This is a MVC application. I tried adding

```
  [Authorize(Roles = @"Doamin\Group")] 

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Is this the right way to do this? are there any other options/ways to do this. 
Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure [WindowsTokenRoleProvider](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/ASP.NET/0420__Authentication-Authorization/ConfiguringtheWindowsTokenRoleProvider.htm), Then you can use:

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"Group")]
```

But you may encounter some "security" restrictions when querying the provider programatically. If so then switch to a custom AD role provider. One example would be [this](http://slalomdev.blogspot.com/2008/08/active-directory-role-provider.html) but there are sure to be more out there.